# R: Embedding a PDF file through iframe in Flexdashboard opens the pdf file in a new tab

Tags: r, pdf, shiny, flexdashboard

I have built a Shiny app through Flexdashboard and I'm having an isssue which I am incapable of solving. I embeded a local PDF file using this code (minimal reproducible example, remove the '##' but not the '###' to test it with any pdf you have):

````
---
title: "Random Title"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    social: menu
runtime: shiny
---

## ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
## ```

PDF
=====================================

### CV

## ```{r}
tags$iframe(style = "height:850px; width:100%; scrolling=yes",  src = "randomPDF.pdf")
## ```
````

My problem is that when I run the App, it opens two tabs: one with the Shiny App (with the PDF well embeded, which is nice) but also a new tab only with the pdf. I want this to stop happening, and I'm struggling to achieve it.

Comment: When I run the shiny app with a .PDF, Adobe opens with just the PDF and then also the shiny app in the web browser with the pdf. not sure why. But once you host the app, you would only see the pdf in the shiny app

Comment: @DanielJachetta that is correct, but when I open the app on mobile, it opens the pdf and the app itself again. I was wondering if it is a way to avoid that.